# HTML Form Submission From Sub Domain, But Processed By Domain. Is It Possible?

Tags: php, html

I have this simple html form :

```
<form action="../../process.php" method="POST">
----SOME INPUT HERE----
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and that form located under this folder : **/public_html/userweb/subdomain.domain.com/form.php** while the process.php is located under **/public_html** folder.

the problem is... /public_html/userweb/subdomain.domain.com is actually a sub-domain's root folder and /public_html is the TLD's root folder.

my question is can a HTML form submission in sub-domain process by TLD? if so, how to do it? because that form always search process.php under subdomain.domain.com/process.php not domain.com/process.php

Comment: You can but you would have to either use the full TLD (eg: http://www.domain.com/form.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `action` of the `form` could be any URL, but not the path in the server.

You just need to set the action like:

```
<form action ="//domain.com/process.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 3):

A form action can be *any* url. For example, this form submits a search query to google:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/">
    <p><input name="q"></p>
</form>
```

To do what you describe, just use a full url as your `action`, such as `//domain.com/process.php`

Answer (score 1):

AJAX it to the domain you want to send it to, and send it as `jsonp`.

Edit: I was thinking of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), where you are restricted in what datatypes you can transmit cross-domain.

Comment: could you explain you answer bit more ?